# Cookies in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm looking for a good example of storing data in a cookie using ASP.NET. Could someone show me an example?

Comment: -1 for asking a question that could easily be answered by searches on Google and/or MSDN.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if this question came up when you searched on Google, and there was a good answer?

Comment: hey people, i just made a question!

Comment: Why is that everyone talking about how to write cookies but nobody about why to write them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out

[Save Form Data With Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx/)

Answer (score 8):

MSDN is quite your friend : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx

Until then :

```
C#:  
Response.Cookie["cookie_name"] = "value";

VB:  
Response.Cookie("cookie_name") = "value";
```

Comment: Please update answer with this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx.  Site is only in en-US right now.

Answer (score 5):

**How to Create a cookie**

```
HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("mycookie");
mycookie.Value = "chocolate chip please.";
Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
```

**How to Read a cookie**

```
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
Response.Write("Your cookie is: " + mycookie.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google says](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=asp.net%20write%20cookie) "[How to Write a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx)"